# Android: Determine which View clicked within ListView row

Tags: android, listview, view, click

I have a ListView with lots of icons which may be clicked to change the state of their respective row items. I realise that I can create onClick handlers for all of them but I would like to a generic means of identifying which icon (View) has been clicked. (e.g. determine View at touch coords x,y?

Any idea how I can do that?

I am getting row clicks with the below handler:

```
  lvClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3 ) 
    ...
```

On each row I have 5 ImageViews.

Comment: Setting onClick handlers is the way you normally do this.

Comment: @GabeSechan: If I had 100 rows with 5 icons each, surely I wouldn't have to assign 500 onClick handlers though?

Comment: @SparkyNZ show some code

Comment: @SparkyNZ Yes, but you can easily use 1 per object per icon, resuing it for each row.  Quite possibly one for all of them.  The way touch handling works doesn't lend itself to the method you want-  views receive touch events, and then views decide if its a click.  There isn't a top level handler looking for clicks then figuring out what view it is.

Comment: @GabeSechan: OK, so in my case I could reuse 5 handlers. That should mean that in theory I just need to add an onClick handler within my ViewBinder setViewValue() method. I'm currently using ImageViews instead of ImageButtons as I keep getting grey boxes on the ImageButtons and the images keep changing size - something they don't do with ImageViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume all rows are being inflated with the same layout and you are using the holder pattern (http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

This way, you can have a single OnClickListener to "listen" for any of your ImageView (or whatever they are). You only need to set the listener in the momento you actually inflate the view (not when you reuse it), and then set for all ImageView in the same row the row position as the Tag, so, then in the onClick method, you can chech to which row they belong to (by the tag) and which ImageView is it (by the id)

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener

[...]

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    MyHolder holder = null;

    if(convertView != null)
    {
        holder = new MyHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(...)
        holder.imageView1 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.[...] )
        holder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
        holder.imageView2 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.[...] )
        holder.imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);
        [...]

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (HyHolder)convertView.getTag();
        [...]
    }

    holder.imageView1.setTag(position);
    holder.imageView2.setTag(position);

    [...]

    return convertView;
 }


 @Override
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
     int id = v.getId();
     Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();

     [...]
 }
```

Of course you can then optimize this, put the views in an array or whatever or put the OnClickListener outside the Adapter (in the activity, or an instance variable), but this is the basic idea.

As a note, you should check what happens with the onItemClickListener, I'm not pretty sure, but it may cause problems intercepting touches (or it may no, I don't know), but if you're not going to use the whole row click, then you can remove it

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since its the same as I implemented it.. and it provides details such as assignment of the tags etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways, You can tag each ImageView to your AsyncTask(or whatever) you use. Or, refer https://github.com/square/picasso